# https redirect to https (No Cert Warning)

Tags: security, ssl, redirect, https, 301-redirect

Am I right in thinking that in order to redirect an https URL to another https URL without a certificate warning, the first https URL has to have it's own valid certificate and IP address?

Am trying to setup some redirects for http and https from a bunch of domains to a secure URL.

Answer (score 2):

The redirection source page will not load without warning from ssl unless you have a certificate for the domain. This is by design.

To get rid of the additional ip address you could get a SAN certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Certificate?  Yes.  IP address? No, if all clients are capable of doing SNI; otherwise, yes.